# Error: Empty string supplied as input. In a OpenGraph code

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-opengraph

I am developing a website that uses a OpenGraph code to retrieve metadatas from URLs, like titles, images, description, etc... it's working pretty good for some websites, mostly the ones that have the "meta propertys" well defined and organized... BUT, for some URLs I am experiencing an annoying error:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Empty string supplied as input in OpenGraph.php on line 69

and

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in 3article.php on line 26

Of course that if I try to fetch a URL that is not OpenGraph friendly I will probably end up with this error, becouse there will not be anything to show up.. nevertheless I am having this issue in URLs that I know that is OpenGraph friendly, so I really think there is a silly problem in my code that for some URLs it's not working.

OpenGraph.php line 68 to 69:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($HTML);
```

and article3.php line 26 to 27:

```
$graph = OpenGraph::fetch($url);
$image = $graph->image . "\n";
```

If anyone could help me with that, I really appreciate, thanks!

Comment: Do you have any sample code for the HTML you're fetching, or the URL?

Comment: @JosephLust Any post from the New York times doesn't work properly (exemple: http://www.nytimes.com/2012/03/27/us/politics/health-act-arguments-open-with-1867-obstacle.html?_r=1&hp ).. But if you see the source code, all the open graph statements are there, so probably the mistake is on my php script.

Comment: Do you have [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/filesystem.configuration##ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled?

Comment: Where are `$HTML` and `$url` being defined?